# SQL запрос для получения изменения значения

Tags: sql

Вот что я пытаюсь получить из БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно вернуть строку, в момент изменения значения на 1, и строку перед изменением значения на 0 (выделено зелёным). X следующей строки не обязательно больше предыдущей на 1.

Написал примерный код:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT * LAG(y) OVER (ORDER BY id) as prev_val
FROM table WHERE y = 1 OR y = 0
) t
WHERE y <> prev_val
```

Но, к сожалению это не то, что я хотел бы.
Идеи?

Comment: то есть у вас есть столбец `y`, который может быть последовательностью `0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1...` и вам нужно отловить момент когда с 0 на 1 и с 1 на 0 прыгают?

Comment: @Acinit, очевидно имеется в виду, что есть таблица со строками по типу [x: 0, y: 0], [x: 1, y: 0], [x: 2, y: 0], [x: 3, y: 1], [x: 4, y: 1], [x: 5, y: 0] и так далее. По поводу момента, вообще нужно отловить последнюю строку ПЕРЕД тем как значение станет ноль, но момент с 1 на ноль тоже пойдёт.

Comment: Нет, не очевидно. Добавьте уточнение в вопрос пожалуйста, что именно и как у вас хранится.

Answer (score 2):

Создадим таблицу с вашими данными.

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
    x NUMBER,
    y NUMBER
);
```

Наполним её данными.

```
INSERT ALL
    INTO your_table_name (x, y) VALUES (0, 0)
    INTO your_table_name (x, y) VALUES (2, 0)
    INTO your_table_name (x, y) VALUES (4, 0)
    INTO your_table_name (x, y) VALUES (10, 1)
    INTO your_table_name (x, y) VALUES (12, 1)
    INTO your_table_name (x, y) VALUES (15, 0)
    INTO your_table_name (x, y) VALUES (100, 1)
    INTO your_table_name (x, y) VALUES (200, 0)
    INTO your_table_name (x, y) VALUES (1000, 1)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

А затем выполним следующий запрос, который вернёт значения до измненения и после (используйте нужное для вас в контексте)

```
with cte_table as ( --инициализируем ROWNUM как row_number (работает в oracle)
SELECT x, y, ROWNUM AS row_number
FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY x)
select t1.x,t1.y,
       t2.x,t2.y
  from cte_table t1
join cte_table t2 on
t1.row_number = t2.row_number+1 -- используем
where t1.y <> t2.y;
```

Результат

| X | Y | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 15 | 0 | 12 | 1 |
| 100 | 1 | 15 | 0 |
| 200 | 0 | 100 | 1 |
| 1000 | 1 | 200 | 0 |

---

P.S.

Вы можете менять оператор в `where t1.y <> t2.y`, для получения моментов перепрыгивания с 0 на 1 (оператор `>`) или с 1 на 0 (оператор `<`)

Comment: И да, не забудьте, если данный ответ устраивает вас, [примите его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: ок, похоже я слишком упростил задачу. В этой строке "t1.x = t2.x+1", есть проблема с тем, что Х не обязательно больше на 1, он просто больше предыдущего Х.

Comment: @JirenCHAD в таком случае измените ваш вопрос используя кнопку "править". Приведите минимальные данные о том, какие у вас иксы а какие игрики. С условием на это, я изменю свой ответ.

Comment: Окей, изменил. Жду ответа.

Comment: @JirenCHAD изменил ответ, используйте ROWNUM, если в контексте вашего клиента SQL такого нет, создайте ключевые поля для ваших данных самостоятельно, создав счётчик и прогнавшись по данным по порядку возрастания X

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t1.x < t2.x AND t1.y <> t2.y
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t3
                   WHERE t1.x < t3.x
                     AND t3.x < t2.x                              
                   );
```

Если словами: найти такие точки, что первая раньше второй, значения в них различны, и между ними нет других точек.

Работает практически на любой версии любого диалекта.